# Send to child which component child should render - React js

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I have a `<div>` of multiple `<input>`, and an onClick event to open a modal window, which has to render certain div of inputs for closer zoom, but I am using this modal window for rendering a numpad too.

Is there any way to distinguish which component should be rendered? Is there a possibility to send certain component to modal component(child) and then render this component? I tried something like this -

```
<Modal update={this.editValue.bind(this)}>{Numpad}</Modal>
```

or

```
<Modal child={Numpad} update={this.editValue.bind(this)}/>
```

and then in Modal(child)

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...others})}
```

but it doesn't work, throwing invalid element type error. I can just use switch, inside render component of Modal to distinguish which component to render with props.type, but I want more simply way to do it, any tips?

Comment: Why not use two modals and show/hide based on the conditions ?

Comment: Because there can be a more modals then 2...  i dont know now, but it can be around 5+- and create 5x modals for certain of them is bad idea.

Comment: You can have and if else condition and assign whatever you want to render to this variable something like `var Numpad = <div>Hello World</div>` and then render it the way you are doing. this way you can have the same modal render multiple views

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly but you can compose components. Your `Modal` component should have in render `<div> {this.props.children} </div>` and then if you want to display numpad in modal write `<Modal> <Numpad /> </Modal>` and if you want to display inputs `<Modal> <div><Input1/> <Input2/> </div> </Modal>`

Comment: This solution looks nice, i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you correctly, you try to create a tabbed interface within a modal window, so that you could show different content depending on currently active tab. I can see the following solution for that problem.

First, we create the basic component that will hold `Modal` component and its content:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal>
        <div>The content of the first tab</div>
        <div>The content of the second tab</div>
        <div>The content of the third tab</div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Each child (`div`) component above represents the content for each tab in `Modal`.

Now let's create `Modal` component itself:

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tabIndex: 0
    };
  }

  switchTabs(tabIndex) {
    this.setState({
      tabIndex
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(this, 0)}>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(this, 1)}>2</button>
        <button onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(this, 2)}>3</button>
        <div>
          {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) =>
            index === this.state.tabIndex && child
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

We keep the index of active tab (`tabIndex`) as a part of component's local state. We also show three buttons for switching between these tabs.

Finally, we iterate over components children using `React.Children.map` and show that child whose `index` corresponds to current `tabIndex`.

Try the snippet below.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tabIndex: 0
    };
  }
  
  switchTabs(tabIndex) {
    this.setState({
      tabIndex
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(this, 0)}>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(this, 1)}>2</button>
        <button onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(this, 2)}>3</button>
        <div>
          {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) =>
            index === this.state.tabIndex && child
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal>
        <div>
          <img src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/4226954?v=3&s=400" height="200" />
        </div>
        <div style={{ height: '200px', width: '200px', marginTop: '5px' }}>The second tab</div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/810671?v=3&s=400" height="200" />
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```